# Oracle SQL - exclude weekends from date range query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query were i pull data between 2 dates using the following.

```
AND TRLRACT.trndte BETWEEN (TRUNC(sysdate -3) + 02.5/24) AND (TRUNC(sysdate) + 2.5/24)
```

is there any way to have it exclude Saturday and Sunday when pulling data

Answer (score 1):

You can check for day of the week in several ways, for example with

```
to_char(trndte, 'Dy') not in ('Sat', 'Sun')
```

(ignoring issues of NLS language). However, your days seem to start and end at 2:30 am, is something at 2 am on a Monday actually considered to be "Sunday"? If so, you should test `trndte - 2.5/24` instead of `trndte` itself.